# Monero GUI on Linux Mint - how to open wallet file from a separate device / USB stick

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, linux

With the CLI wallet, I can access the wallet file in the same directory, on a USB, due to using the cd command to /media/devicename. However, the GUI does not seem to recognise devices, to open the wallet file from, only the Home directory. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3):

When opening the GUI, select "Open a wallet from file"

[image: Screenshot of opening the Monero GUI wallet]

After that, in the file picker you can go to any directory.

[image: Screenshot of the file picker]

You could navigate to `/media/yourusb/yourwallet.keys` by clicking through the different directories (you might have to go to `/` first by clicking Computer on the left), or you could just directly type the path `/media/yourusb` into the File name box and press open.